# How to access a WCF service from F# in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: wcf, f#, wsdl

In .Net Framework 4.7.2  F#, I have been using:

```
FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
```

with

```
  type WSDL =  WsdlService<"http://...ServiceHost.svc">
  type AV   =  WsdlService<"http://...ServiceHost.svc">
```

to access my local WCF network service from an F# .fs file.

How do I access the WCF service from F# client when .NET Core 3.1 is being used?

TIA

If not, what is the recommended upgrade path for WCF/petapoco/PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an old type provider from F# 3.0, and it depended on svcutil for code generation. You could reference its nuget package but it's possible (likely) there is no support for the dotnet-svcutil tool.  But you can use WCF from C#, so:

1. Add a new C# project to your solution
2. Add Connected Service in Visual Studio and configure your end point, this will generate the necessary code, build your project (and test that it works)
3. From your F# project, add reference to this C# project, and `open ProjectName`
4. Create your type, and use it from F#. You will get intellisense on the types so the user experience is not that different from the type provider.
5. If needed you can publish the self-contained exe:
   `dotnet publish -r win10-x64 -c Release -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:PublishTrimmed=true`

Comment: I do not see a WCF Service to add ?

Comment: @AlanWayne could you be a bit more specific? Usually you can add the service via its http endpoint referring to the wsdl file from VS. Then in both the C# and F# code you can crate a type, something like `type MyPortType`, and refer to it in code. If you can generate the code manually via svcutil, then compile it and reference the project or dll. Easiest way is to build an empty C# dll that includes your WCF service, and reference it from F#, that will give you access to all the types.

Comment: My Error. The WCF service is available, but only if the project is a C# .NET Core, .NET Standard, or ASP.NET Core Web Application.  I missed that in my initial reading. Good reference at: Use the WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool at docs.Microsoft.com    Thanks